# How do I make each individual a user from a model?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

This is probably simple but for me it has proved to be a headache.
I'd like to make each teacher from TeacherData model to be a user using the first_name as the username and email as the password. Here are my models.

School model

```
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
```

User model

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Teacher's model

```
class TeacherData(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

If there's anything else required let me know and I'll add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done at the model level as shown.

```
class TeacherData(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.user = User.objects.create_user(username=self.first_name,password=str(self.email),is_teacher = True,is_student = False,school_id=self.school.id)
            self.user.save()  # mandatory as create_user is not recognized as save operation
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks. Working well well. The problem is when I try to edit, it complains of UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_user.username. It's like it's trying to create another user by saving the edited teacher. How do I work this out????